# Create webhook notification url in microsoft onenote

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I am trying to subscribe webhook in one note getting following error:

```
Client error: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions resulted in a 400 Bad Request response:
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidRequest",
"message": "Subscription validation request failed. Response must ex (truncated...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but unfortunately OneNote webhooks via Microsoft Graph is not supported yet.

Comment: thanks for replay , is their any alternative solution please let me know..

Comment: We only support OneNote webhooks for personal accounts and apps, not for work or Office365 apps/users. Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-sync. We will need: 1. Value of "X-AuthenticatedUserId" and "X-AuthenticatedAppId" from the response of any OneNote API request (example, GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/notebooks)
2. URL that we'll call when there are any changes coming from your app users. Let me know when you are ready with this.

Comment: Hi Mnajusha , I want to change onedrive file permission to readony please suggest